# How do I configure webpack-dev-server to turn off "beforeunload" events on the browser before reload?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, webpack-dev-server, onbeforeunload

My form pages have a `beforeunload` event/function set on the window to warn the user to save their changes before moving on to a different page or refreshing. It works great, and looks something like this:

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", myCustomWindowBeforeUnloadFunction);
```

The problem is when running in development, every time I change a file in my IDE, Webpack Dev Server attempts to auto-reload the page. I want to turn off this `beforeunload` event so I don't keep getting nagged with this alert in Chrome:

```
Are you sure you want to leave the page? Data you have entered may not be saved.
```

Is there a way I can run a custom function in the browser before Webpack Dev Server attempts to reload the page?

Comment: you can catch the hot update event of webpack  described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868821/listen-for-hot-update-events-on-the-client-side-with-webpack-dev-derver and then remove that event by using removeEventListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
if (process.env.DEV) {
  window.addEventListener('message', ({ data: { type } }) => {
    if (type === 'webpackInvalid') {
      $(window).off('beforeunload');
    } else if (type === 'INIT_INSTANCE') {
      $(window).on('beforeunload', myCustomWindowBeforeUnloadFunction);
    }
  });
}
```

I've added `process.env.DEV` with [`EnvironmentPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/) to make sure that code doesn't make it to production. You could also use `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'`, which works without adding `EnvironmentPlugin`, as [Webpack adds that automatically](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/).

Or, using [HMR's `addStatusHandler` function](https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/#addstatushandler):

```
if (process.env.DEV && module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();

  module.hot.addStatusHandler((status) => {
    if (status === 'prepare') {
      $(window).off('beforeunload');
    } else if (/apply|abort|fail/.test(status)) {
      $(window).on('beforeunload', myCustomWindowBeforeUnloadFunction);
    }
  });
}
```

Note `module.hot` will be there if you are using [`HotModuleReplacementPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/hot-module-replacement-plugin/), no need to import that, as explained [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/):

> If [Hot Module Replacement](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/) has been enabled via the [`HotModuleReplacementPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/hot-module-replacement-plugin/), its interface will be exposed under the [`module.hot` property](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#modulehot-webpack-specific). Typically, users will check to see if the interface is accessible, then begin working with it.

Also, maybe instead of checking for `apply`, `abort` or `fail` in the second condition, you could use [`idle`](https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/#status).

Comment: YAS!! That first block worked. I don't have a `window.process` or a `window.module` so I'm not sure where that's supposed to come from. But I can just listen for "message" like you did above and disable it. That works perfectly. We don't use webpack-dev-server in prod so I'm pretty sure the `webpackInvalid` message will never be fired, right?

Comment: There should not be any `webpackInvalid` messages in production, but it's a good practice to remove development-only code from your production builds, which is what those `if (process.env.DEV)` do. Anyway, I didn't notice I added that on my projects. The default way to do that check is `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'`.

Comment: I have also added some additional details about `module.hot`. You should not import that, it will be exposed by `HotModuleReplacementPlugin`, so it should work as well, even though you might see some errors if using TypeScript.

Comment: Wait. Where are you adding this code? On the server side somewhere? I put this in my js on the client/browser side. `process.env.*` is Node JS and `window.addEventListener` is in the browser, right? I feel like you have some crazy awesome method of injecting code in the browser through `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: It's client-side. `process.env.*` is Node.js, which is where Webpack runs, so you have access to that in compilation time. For example, if you add `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"` but then run a production build, that if and its content will be gone.

Comment: If you want to inject additional compile-time properties to `process.env`, you should use [EnvironmentPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/). If you want to inject additional compile-time properties that are not inside `process.env`, you should use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/).